# Conditional cast from PFFile toPFFile always succeed

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, casting, pffile

I get a warming of "Conditional cast from PFFile toPFFile always succeed" which highlighted `if let tempProductPicture = self.askProductImageArray[0] as? PFFile`. What is the best way to solve it? Thanks

```
var askProductImageArray = [PFFile]()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    let query = PFQuery(className: "products")
    query.whereKey("title", equalTo: labelTitleText)
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects: [PFObject]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
            if error != nil {
            }
            for object in objects! {
                self.askProductImageArray.append(object.objectForKey("detailsImage") as! PFFile)
                self.askTable.reloadData()
            }
            if let tempProductPicture = self.askProductImageArray[0] as? PFFile {
                tempProductPicture.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock { data, error in
                    if data == nil {

                    } else if error != nil {
                    } else {
                        self.productPicture.image = UIImage(data: data!)
                    }
                }
            }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `self.askProductImageArray` is an array of type `PFFIle` so there is no need to do a`s? PFFile` because swift is strongly typed language and it will hold only `PFFile` so remover `as? PFFile` at the end.

In your case you don't need to do `if let` at all, you just need to check if item already exist.

you can do something like this

```
if self.askProductImageArray.count > 0 {
let tempProduct = self.askProductImageArray[0]
// and do rest 
}
```

Comment: If I remove as? PFFile, there is an error of "Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'PFFile'"

Comment: You don't need to do if let at all, you just need to check array count and then  use that object